# websockets realTime tracking

Tags: nginx, websocket, real-time

I am kind of new to websockets. I know websockets can be used to pass continuous data to a server. I will explain what I want to do with an example. Lets say there are people asking for help from the police. These people report their position as they move every 30 seconds to the server. The police members also report their position as they move every 30 seconds to the server. Let say one person ask for help I need to connect that person to the nearest police man. In order to do that do i need to store an updated location of the police and the people every 30 seconds in a database and query for nearest policy or there is another faster way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what websockets provide. They do not provide real time tracking of location - websockets provide a protocol that you can establish an open socket using HTTP.

Once that is done you'd need the client to push location data to the server, that is not something built into websockets itself which is only a method of always-on communication.

Comment: sorry if I wasnot clear. I know websockets are used to send data. So basically once a connection is established between user and a server the user can push the updated location to the server every 30 seconds my question is it possible to pass that location from the server some one who is nearby with out storing the info in database. For example user location is give by latitude 20 and longituide 30. Can I pass that Info to another nearby user from server directly without storing it in a database

Comment: Yes, there are libraries out there that will let you estimate distance so you can say "send this to all users X distance away".

Comment: can you elaborate more or share these libraries